# XSLT Access looping number for template

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have a requirement as follows.
Sample XML:

```
<root>
    <bookseries>
        <author/>
        <version/>
        <book>
            <date>1</date>
            <price>10</price>
        </book>
        <book>
            <date>2</date>
            <price>20</price>
        </book>
        <book>
            <date>3</date>
            <price>30</price>
        </book>
    </bookseries>
</root>
```

Now I want to apply a template to all **book** elements.
What I am currently doing in my template is:

```
<xsl:template match="//book">
    <!--here I want to see which book element is being copied and also format its data. 
    I am not getting the current order number of template-->
</xsl:template>
```

Currently using this approach, I get only first book elements data repitatively for 3 times. I need to access each book elements data in respective template call. How can I do this?

Comment: So where do you exactly apply that template you have posted, how does the template body look exactly? Inside the body the `book` element is the context node so use relative expressions like `price` to access the price of the matched book and not `//price` which would select all `price` elements and with a `value-of` and XSLT 1 then only output the first `price` element in the document.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
<xsl:template match="//book">
    <xsl:copy>
       <!-- capturing child with different element name to show only result-->
        <d><xsl:value-of select="date"/></d>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="price"/></p>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

When you match template than inside the template you will capture child with there name not wit "`//`", in that case it run on whole file rater than current element as @martin Already mentioned in above comment.